# What are the best environments to write c++ on a Mac?

Tags: c++, xcode, ide

I have been switched from windows and ubuntu to macbook and I have researched for the best environments for programming c++.

The one I found is Xcode which has many fan but the problem with it is the editor does not guess anything or when I type something it doesn't bring the similar keywords which I can choose from!

Is there any other software like visual studio or dev c++ which is powerful and fast and handy on macbook? By the way I prefer a free or cheap software.

Comment: Xcode has one of the best code completion implementations available for C++. How does it not work? Also, try Vim with clang_complete or Sublime Text 2 with SublimeClang.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274053/is-there-a-way-to-have-xcode-4-autocomplete-like-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best IDE doesn't exist really, it's your own choice...

There is an list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Macintosh_software#Developer_tools_and_IDEs) of Macintosh Software for programming.

Another popular C++ IDE :

- Qt Creator
- Code::Blocks
- NetBeans

Answer (score 2):

I vote for Xcode. Regarding the intellisense you used to in VS, Xcode have that only that it doesn't pop-up automatically. you need to press "esc" for that to pop-up. [more here](http://www.michaelbowersox.com/2008/12/29/xcode-intellisense-shortcut/)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [QT Creator](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Developer-Tools/)? It's quite fast and has decent autocompletion.

Comment: I use it with linux and like it a lot. It has the advantage to be cross-platform and not very intrusive. And I don't do any Qt developpement.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you will not found any best environment then the xCode. Try to learn xCode, Surely you will love it.